# How to get Wikipedia W from Linux Libertine?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, characters, libertine

How can I get the Wikipedia-looking crossing-w from Linux Libertine font?

They talk about it on [their homepage](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?L=1) and in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Libertine#Usage), but I can't find an example of how to actually produce it.

Fyi I'm using `xetex` with `fontspec`.

Comment: I guess you're looking for this:`\libertineGlyph{W.alt}`

Comment: @cgnieder You could turn this into an answer. (And it assumes you've loaded the `libertineotf` package.) Is there a way to do it without?

Comment: @AlanMunn: It should be possible with `fontspec`'s `Alternate` feature.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The “official” way, is to activate stylistic set 5 feature, `StylisticSet=5` fontspec option. If you to use it locally then you can define a “font family” with that option, and if you want it globally you should pass it to `\setmainfont`. This is also the most portable way, as the glyph name (`W.alt`) or the private use area code point (`U+E02F`) can change in the future since they are “internal” to the font and should not concern its users, only the OpenType features are the “public” interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\libertinew[StylisticSet=5]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Wikipedia}\par
\textsc{\libertinew Wikipedia}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you know to use 5 as the StylisticSet?

Comment: I couldn't find it in the documentation (not mentioned explicitly, but I don't know German anyway), so I opened the font in FontForge and checked the alternates of the W glyph :).

Comment: Man, there is got to be an easier way of doing these things...

Comment: @drozzy: yes, it is called proper documentations (which reminds me to properly document my own fonts :p).

Comment: What would be the official way if one doesn't use XeLaTeX? `\libertineGlyph` works with pdflatex as well...

Comment: @cgnieder: If one can’t use an OpenType cabable engine, then accessing the glyph directly would be the only way AFAIK (unless it is made into a fake ligature in the TFM files, which is very unlikely).

Comment: @AlanMunn (+ drozzy): You could also examine the Stylistic Sets as described in [How to find out which glyphs are different in an OpenType style set?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75720).

Comment: Interestingly I receive a warning with `Linux Libertine O` (`fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font" OpenType feature 'Variant=5' (+ss05) not available for font 'LinuxLibertineO/B' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.`), but the W shows as expected.

Answer (score 9):

The character is accessible through `\libertineGlyph{W.alt}` or `\libertineGlyph{uniE02F}`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\libertineGlyph{W.alt}\textsc{ikipedia} \libertineGlyph{uniE02F}\textsc{ikipedia}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As Andrey Vihrov pointed out in his comment you can also access the glyph with `\char"E02F` without having to load `libertineotf`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\char"E02F\relax\textsc{ikipedia}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found out that `Alternate` doesn't quite work. But you can get the glyph with `\char"E02F\relax`, then `libertineotf` is not needed.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov Ah, I should have thought of that. It's quite obvious, actually...

Comment: Does it work as well if you put the W in the `\textsc`? The way it is, the kerning looks a little off, repositioning it might help.

Comment: Well, one probably wants to put everything in a macro called `\WikipediaMark`, say, so you stick a manual `\kern -0.05em` or something in there.

Comment: @doncherry I haven't tried it out (I can't say why, actually) but I guess it does. But if it doesn't there's still kahen's suggestion.

Comment: @cgnieder: Hmm, with the `\libertineGlyph` versions, it fixes the kerning, but the W appears strangely, I'd say it's italic. No idea why. `\textsc{\char"E02F\relax ikipedia}` looks good -- correct letter and right kerning.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov How in the world did you find the code for that letter? Can you share your wizard ways...

Comment: @drozzy You find it in the libertine manual in the »Glyphs« section