# Issues with pgf package: "There is no ... in font nullfont" but no tkzpicture usage

Tags: tikz-pgf, warnings

I am trying to use a template listed here:

http://people.debian.org/~dburrows/resume-cls.html

but the `pdf` output is all nonsense, with a few bullet points and random lines - but no text. I think this is due to a dependency with the `pgf` package.

My issue is very similar to this post:

[tikzpicture "There is no ... in font nullfont", but no extraneous text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147722/tikzpicture-there-is-no-in-font-nullfont-but-no-extraneous-text)

but my examples are not using `tkzpicture` or other identified problematic code. I suspect that I need to correct something here, which is the only code in the document that uses `pgf`:

```
% Usage: \@setupshading{width}{height}{start}{end}
\newcommand{\@setupshading}[4]{%
  \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{@ruleshading}{#2}{%
    color(0pt)=(#3); color(#1)=(#4)%
  }
}

\newcommand{\pgfrule}[4]{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{@ruleshading}{#2}{%
      color(0pt)=(#3); color(#1)=(#4)%
    }
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,0)}{\pgfbox[left,bottom]{\pgfuseshading{@ruleshading}}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\lrule}[2]{\pgfrule{#1}{#2}{rulestartcolor}{ruleendcolor}}
\newcommand{\rrule}[2]{\pgfrule{#1}{#2}{ruleendcolor}{rulestartcolor}}
```

I have excerpts of the errors from my logs below. How can I resolve these errors?

Here are the excerpts from my `.log` file:

```
Package pgfshade Warning: This package is obsolete. pgf.sty will load shade man
agement automatically on input line 17.

) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count102
\XC@countmixins=\count103
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty
Package: times 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
)
! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or inst
alled font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
```

And there is more:

```
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 24.
! Font T1/ptm/bx/n/10=ptmb8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or insta
lled font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
extract@font ...ont font@name external@font relax 
                                                  font@name relax csname f@e...

define@newfont ...ong@fontshape else extract@font 
                                                  fi endgroup 
pickup@font ...ifx font@name relax define@newfont 
                                                  fi 
selectfont  ...ape /f@size endcsname }pickup@font 
                                                  font@name size@update enc@...

textbf  ...hmode@bgroup text@command {#1}bfseries 
                                                  check@icl #1check@icr expa...

@begin@tempboxa ...tempboxa #1{color@begingroup #2
                                                  color@endgroup }def width ...

@imakebox [#1][#2]#3->@begin@tempboxa hbox {#3}
                                               setlength @tempdima {#1}hb@xt...

maketitle ...xtbf {Large {@authorname  @email }}}}
                                                  vspace {headerbuffer }par ...
l.24 \maketitle

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \T1/ptm/b/n/10=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed fon
t not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
\pickup@font ...\font@name \relax \define@newfont 
                                                  \fi 
\selectfont  .../\f@size \endcsname }\pickup@font
```

and here is the `There is no ... in font nullfont!` issue:

```
\maketitle ...{\Large {\@authorname \ \@email }}}}
                                                  \vspace {\headerbuffer }\p...
l.24 \maketitle

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

Missing character: There is no J in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no Q in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no R in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+pcr on input line 24.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pcr.fd
File: t1pcr.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pcr.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pcr/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/pcr/b/n' tried instead on input line 24.

! Font T1/pcr/bx/n/14.4=pcrb8t at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or ins
talled font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
extract@font ...ont font@name external@font relax 
                                                  font@name relax csname f@e...
```

I also believe that my distro is up to date, from the following output:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../jobsearch/resume$ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5

[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../jobsearch/resume$ tlmgr update --list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TeX Live 2013 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: no updates available
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me. May be you need an update of your tex distro.

Comment: @HarishKumar I tested my distro, and it is up to date on the 2013 frozen distro (I installed tex-live from Ubuntu's package manager). I am starting to suspect the `pgf` package, but I do not know how to proceed. I updated my questions, let me know if you have suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some local additions to your TeX system? Can you add `\listfiles` to the input and edit the resulting `File list` into the question (from the `.log`)?

Comment: Which Ubuntu packages do you have installed exactly? Are you missing any standard TeX font packages? (For example, cm super or similar.) Also, delete `~/.texlive2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my `missfont.log`, which had lots of missing dependencies. After running `texlive-fonts-recommended`, everything worked. I think that this command helps with Debian and Ubuntu distros.