# Random points in a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, random-numbers

I have made a graph as shown in the following figure:

[image: Plotted graphs]

For each rectangle I'd like to generate *n* random points in it, is it possible?

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\axisdefaultheight,
    xlabel = Time $(s)$,
    ylabel = Frequency,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 13,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 4000,
]

    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (40,100);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (40,0) rectangle (80,100);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (80,0) rectangle (120,100);

    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (0,100) rectangle (40,200);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (40,100) rectangle (80,200);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (80,100) rectangle (120,200);

    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (0,200) rectangle (40,300);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (40,200) rectangle (80,300);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (80,200) rectangle (120,300);

    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (0,300) rectangle (40,400);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (40,300) rectangle (80,400);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (80,300) rectangle (120,400);


\end{axis}
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=15pt},decorate]   (0,0) -- node[below=16pt] {\textbf{C}} (3.2,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate]   (10.8,0) -- node[xshift=10pt] {\rotatebox{-90}{\textbf{band}}} (10.8,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**: I realized that my original answer (below) does not work for newer versions of pgfplots (since there is some mismatch between `xmax`, `ymax` and the explicit coordinates you are using for the rectangles. I fixed that, and also split the rectangles in smaller pieces. The number of points is controlled by `samples=100`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\axisdefaultheight,
    xlabel = Time $(s)$,
    ylabel = Frequency,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 130,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 4000,
]
%
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (0,00) rectangle (40,1000);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (40,00) rectangle (80,1000);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (80,00) rectangle (120,1000);
%
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (0,1000) rectangle (40,2000);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (40,1000) rectangle (80,2000);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (80,1000) rectangle (120,2000);
%
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (0,2000) rectangle (40,3000);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (40,2000) rectangle (80,3000);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (80,2000) rectangle (120,3000);
%
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (0,3000) rectangle (40,4000);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (40,3000) rectangle (80,4000);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (80,3000) rectangle (120,4000);
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,12}
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\X}{mod((#1-1),3)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{int((#1-1)/3+1)}
    \addplot[scatter,clip=true, clip marker paths=true,
        only marks, mark=*, samples=100,point meta=int(#1)             
    ]({20+40*\X+20*rand},{-500+1000*\Y+500*rand});}
\end{axis}
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=15pt},decorate]   (0,0) -- node[below=16pt] {\textbf{C}} (3.2,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate]   (10.8,0) -- node[xshift=10pt] {\rotatebox{-90}{\textbf{band}}} (10.8,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**(for older versions of pgfplots, produces your screen shot from your code):
I am not quite sure which rectangles you are talking about. This answer takes them to be the large ones, i.e. those which run from `x=0` to `x=12`, but I will be happy to divide them for you. I also took `n=100`, which is controlled by `samples=100`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\axisdefaultheight,
    xlabel = Time $(s)$,
    ylabel = Frequency,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 13,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 4000,
]

    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (40,100);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (40,0) rectangle (80,100);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, line width=1pt] (80,0) rectangle (120,100);

    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (0,100) rectangle (40,200);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (40,100) rectangle (80,200);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green, line width=1pt] (80,100) rectangle (120,200);

    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (0,200) rectangle (40,300);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (40,200) rectangle (80,300);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red, line width=1pt] (80,200) rectangle (120,300);

    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (0,300) rectangle (40,400);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (40,300) rectangle (80,400);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange, line width=1pt] (80,300) rectangle (120,400);
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4}
    {\addplot[scatter,clip=true, clip marker paths=true,
        only marks, mark=*, samples=100,point meta=int(y/1000)             
    ]({6+6*rand},{-500+1000*#1+500*rand});}
\end{axis}
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=15pt},decorate]   (0,0) -- node[below=16pt] {\textbf{C}} (3.2,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate]   (10.8,0) -- node[xshift=10pt] {\rotatebox{-90}{\textbf{band}}} (10.8,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but whan trying to compile the following errors appear:
`Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!`

What can I do?

Comment: @DavidePisanò That's odd. Both codes run without any errors on my machine. But I have looked up the message [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147722/121799) and made a small change in my first code. Does it run now on your machine?

Comment: No dice, the errors are still there, but the pdf is generated correctly. I'm using LyX 2.2.2 on debian 9.4

Comment: @DavidePisanò I guess the relevant information is which TeX version ou are using? TeXLive or MikTeX? Did you update them recently? (It is very hard to debug an error that I do not get.)

Comment: This is the output from LyX register:
`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.5.28)  13 JUN 2018 18:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
...
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3`

They should be up to date, I reinstalled them 2 weeks ago

Comment: @DavidePisanò Well, I guess you'd greatly benefit from updating your TeXLive distribution. You have a 2016 version but now is 2018. You should have a TeXLive manager somewhere and have to tell it to update.

Comment: Thank you fur the suggestion, now I'm struggling to update TeXLive since in Debian 9 the latest version in the official repository is the 2016 one.

Comment: @DavidePisanò I guess you could ask a separate question on this. I myself work on MacOS and I am not at all an expert on these issues, but others are (yet do not see our conversation) and I am sure you will get a good answer.

Comment: Well, I'll do that for sure