# segmentation fault when executing xdvipdfmx through latexmk using externalise library of tikz/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, latexmk, tikz-external, xdvipdfmx

I'm using latexmk (calling xelatex with pdfxe) and have a makefile around it, that calls the externalised makefile from tikz/pgf. The code worked fine list year (last time compiled June-2020).
Meanwhile I've updated my operating system to Mac OS Big Sur, tex live and all packages, ran the fmtutil scripts, ...

I have three documents, compiling with the same setup:

- a test document: works fine
- the presentation material for one course, I'm teaching: works fine
- the presentation material for another course, I'm teaching: crashes

For the one that crashes:
I am including about 250 externalized tikz-pictures (total size about 13 MB) into the main document (total size about 4.5 MB).

For the one that works: the final output file size is about 5.6 MB. The size of the included figures is about 3.6 MB.

So I started commenting code in the one that crashes: no success.

The error I'm getting is:

```
xdvipdfmx zsh: segmentation fault
xdvipdfmx: Command for 'xdvipdfmx' gave return code 11
```

I've now invested about 48 hours in commenting various parts of the material: it does not depend on the size or a specific line, but it is reproducible. E.g. at some point it crashed at a certain chapter. Commenting it, removed the error. Then adding everting but the heading: worked. Adding the heading afterwards: works.
Including the next chapter (contents): crashes on the first run; ignoring this and adding one more chapter: works on the second run. This is reproducible after restarting the computer. 
I've checked for cross section links and unresolved labels: all commented.

Questions:

- Generic: Can anyone point me in a good direction?
- More specific: why is `xdvipdfmx` involved at all, if I call `latexmk` with the option `-pdfxe`?
- what updates might have been made to such an installation since mid 2020 until beginning 2021? (I've reverted to latexmk 4.67, as I've seen the mods on calling xdvipdfmk with the flag -E since September 2020. That was not it.) Anything similar, that I've missed?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1:**

I now ran `tlmgr restore -all` and afterwards had to update `amsmath`.
So basically I reverted my tex installation back to the days, when I still could compile my code. This seems to have eliminated the issue.

So next step is to find out, which of the many many reverted packages could have caused the issue. Hot candidates are the ones, which I'm only using in the document that crashes, but not in the others. Here's the list of *potential suspects*:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{toolbox}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
```

I'll be digging deeper to figure out which package exactly caused the trouble, but as I did not change the way I'm invoking `latexmk` from my `Makefile`, I now can exclude `latexmk` to be the sinner.

**UPDATE 2:**

When compiling with the latest and greatest version of packages (2020-01-08), I have seen [this error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147722/tikzpicture-there-is-no-in-font-nullfont-but-no-extraneous-text) multiple times in the log file

```
Missing character: There is no 3 in font nullfont!
```

with various numbers, where 3 is only an example here. `xdvipdfmx` runs fine with only few of them, but for now I believe, I have seen warnings/errors from `xdvipdfmx` only, when `xelatex` produced the `Missing character` warning.
It appears to me, that this is something very old popping up again after an update of some package. While my first intuition points towards `tikz`, I cannot help but puzzling about the fact that I could reproduce/remove the error by simply adding removing a `subsubsection` command. I tried with and without the corresponding `label` (as I thought this to be a common denominator between my a `tikzpicture` and a `subsubsection`, but the `label` command made no difference).
So if anyone is on to the all-of-a-sudden-popping-up again `Missing character` issue running xelatex, this might or might not be related.
Degugging this takes time, but I'll keep you posted.

Comment: xdvipdfmx is involved as xelatex basically runs first `xelatex --no-pdf` to create a xdv and then calls xdvipdfmx to convert this xdv to a pdf. Try to split this too, if this also crashes, you could use `xdvipdfmx -vv file` to get more info.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer: according to http://personal.psu.edu/~jcc8/software/latexmk/latexmk-470b.txt the option -pdfxe for latexmk should directly make the pdf. takes longer time, but should about calling xdvipdfmx.
Even I use this option, xdvipdfmx is getting called anyways. Hmmm?!?

Comment: Xdvipdfmx is always used by xelatex.

Comment: To reinforce @UlrikeFischer's point, there's a useful addition I should make to the description of the -pdfxe option in the latexmk documentation.  This is just to mention that if xelatex is invoked without the -no-pdf option, then internally it still invokes xdvipdfmx.

Comment: For debugging this problem: 1. Is there anything that looks significant in latexmk's output between where it starts running xdvipdfmx and the error message quoted in the question?  2. What happens if you run xelatex from the command line **without** the -no-pdf option?  3. Ditto if you give it the -no-pdf option and then invoke xdvipdfmx on the xdv file?

Comment: @JohnCollins: 1. nope: I ran it verbously: actually xdvipdfm counts up the slides nicely [1][2].... I remember though to have seen some character issues. All of a sudden it crashes with the zsh segfault message. It's in the middle of writing a word in the pdf file.
I tried 3. But as the call to latexmk is coming from another loop and a makefile (all due to the externalisation library of tikz), it's actually not so easy to do these kind of manual calls. same for the ones UlrikeFischer suggested. No doubt this would be the right thing to do.

Comment: But by now I've identified the revert of my latest updates solves the problem - not permanently, but another good clue to track down during lockdown. ;-)