# tikzposter: “Missing character: There is no ... in font nullfont!”

Tags: fonts, tikzposter

The compilation of the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
% \font\nullfont=cmr10
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

produces the following warnings:

```
Missing character: There is no F in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
```

I tried to resort the `\font\nullfont=cmr10` trick from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147736/18401) but I couldn't locate the culprit lines in the (up to date for a current TeX Live 2022 distribution: 2014/01/15 v2.0) `tikzposter.cls` file.

Comment: tikzposter creates one large tikzpicture and as with every tikzpicture text outside node are typeset with the nullfont. If you want to add text use the commands it provides, or use `\node{Foo};`.