# TiKZPoster: Title: Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!

Tags: tikzposter

I recently updated my TexLive distribution to the 2023 version, but in doing so
I've started receiving a number of warnings from my `tikzposter`:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
%\font\nullfont=cmr10
\title{TikZTests}%
% \author{John Doe}%
% \institute{World Government}%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

While the compilation works:

```
latexmk -C  tikzposter.tex && latexmk tikzposter.tex
```

There are a number of annoying warnings about missing characters:

```
Output written on tikzposter.pdf (1 page, 39473 bytes).
Transcript written on tikzposter.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'tikzposter.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'tikzposter.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'tikzposter.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'tikzposter.pdf'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  =====Latex reported missing or unavailable character(s).
=====See log file for details.
Latexmk: ====List of undefined refs and citations:
  Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
  Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
  Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

Anyone know where these come from? They only show up if the `\maketitle` macro
is used, and is there some way to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674062/tikzposter-missing-character-there-is-no-in-font-nullfont

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No it is not a duplicate. That question is related to content outside of the tikzposter objects, this is related to the usage of the `\maketitle`. Additionally, `\maketitle` cannot be put inside a `\node{}`, making the answer to their question inapplicable to this one.

Comment: If you are not scaling the title, you can avoid the warning with `\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{TikZTests}
\makeatletter
\define@key{title}{titletextscale}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in tikzposter. It uses an assignment on a macro instead of defining it.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
%\font\nullfont=cmr10
\title{TikZTests}%
% \author{John Doe}%
% \institute{World Government}%


\makeatletter
\define@key{title}{titletextscale}{\def\TP@titletextscale{#1}} %instead of \TP@titletextscale=1
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like this solved it, but looking at the code (https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/src/master/tikzposter.cls), they seem to actually be doing this already. Is MacTeX distributing a different version of tikzposter?

Comment: looks so, if they don't upload to ctan it won't get into the tex systems.

Comment: Ahh, so that's the crux. I found the issue here mentioning it as well: https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues/42/ctan-does-not-have-a-recent-version