# "Missing character ... in nullfont" error when using Tikz 3D Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

When I compile this minimal example using Tikz 3D Plot with `pdflatex`, version `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)`, I end up with a series of "Missing Character: There is no  in nullfont". Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (P1) at (-5.0, -1.0) {};
  \node (P2) at (5.0, 1.0) {};
  \clip (P1) rectangle (P2);
  \shade[ball color=blue] (0, 0) circle (1);
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rt}{10}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{(90/32)*(-16)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{(90/32)*(\rt-16)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstart}{cos(\start)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sstart}{sin(\start)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cangle}{cos(\angle)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sangle}{sin(\angle)}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(\cstart,\sstart,0)(\cangle,\sangle,0)
    % FIXME: This is not working for some bizarre reason. It used to work in an older version!
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[red, thick]{1}{}{}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The errors dumped to the terminal are:

```
Missing character: There is no - in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no + in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no + in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 3 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 9 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
angles for cross product: phi: 0theta: 0.0
```

This used to work smoothly in a previous version of PDFLaTeX without these errors. The rendered image looks okay, though.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: well it is not new, you perhaps didn't see it as in older tex systems this messages were hidden in the log.  Imho it is harmless, in the style a debug line has not be commented correctly and now prints stray characters in the null font.

Comment: In general, you can follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147736/107497 and temporarily add `\font\nullfont=cmr10` to see the offending characters to possibly track down where they're coming from.  That might not help in this case, since it appears to be a package bug.

Answer (score 5):

It is imho harmless. In tikz-3dplot.sty a comment char has been forgotten:

```
    %DEBUG: show the cross product
    %\draw[->,blue] (\tdplotvertexx,\tdplotvertexy,\tdplotvertexz) 
        -- ++(\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz); %<------------- here
```

The last line should be commented, instead it now prints some chars in nullfont which leads to the message.