How to supress Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!
I am running LuaLaTeX locally on my computer. In my IDE, errors and warning messages are very pronounced.
Specifically, the Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont! error is raising a lot of false alarms - despite being harmless.(https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708053/319072)
I tried the solution here to "see" where the problem occurs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147736/319072
The solution causes normal hf-tikz syntax to no longer work (which I know is expected - it is a troubleshooting method).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\font\nullfont=cmr10
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin{a}a&b&c\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}


How can I suppress this exact error, so my editor only warns me about substantial (non-harmless) errors?

are you sure it is an error and not a warning? typically, it is a warning. the way to get rid of it is to correct the erroneous markup in your input. that is, there is always something wrong if latex is trying to typeset with the null font. pgf/tikz deals with stuff it can't make sense of, when possible, by typesetting it using the null font so it doesn't affect the resulting image. but the source is still wrong.

@cfr I think its a warning actually (how does one tell?), but I don't see any problems with my syntax. My guess is that hf-tikz is typing two semicolons at the end (perhaps as a safety measure)

imho, it is a bug and should be reported to the author. and, yes, it is definitely the package: even an example from the documentation produces the warnings. you tell the difference between an warning and an error by reading the console and/or the log. depending on the options you use, an error may stop compilation (a fatal error ends compilation), whereas a warning will not. latex labels its messages Error, Warning, Info etc. tex reports errors, too, and then you do not get the LaTeX Error format. generally, info-level are written only to the log by default (not the console).

what is the optional argument of \tikzmarkend for?

@cfr Thank you for your help in identifying the issue. I've never submitted a bug report before, would you mind suggesting a way to do so. If you want, you could even submit it yourself.

@cfr  I thought you needed to say which tikzmarkin you are closing? it's labeled a. Is it really optional? What if there were two overlapping highlights?

yes, but it is defined to take 2 arguments. the identifier is the required one e.g. \tikzmarkend{a} but there's also an optional one before that which it uses as \tikz[.... id=#2] #1 ;. I was wondering what that first argument was intended for. as for bug reports, I'd suggest emailing the email address in the footer of page 1 of the manual and including your mwe from the question, together with a link to this thread.

@cfr I will inform the author of this thread, and also check out the optional argument in the manual. Thank you again for your time and help.

You get such a message with an empty \tikz command terminated by a semicolon:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
aaa\tikz;

\end{document}

This can be corrected by using \tikz{} instead.
In the case of hf-tikz the \tikzmarkend command is such an empty tikz command. Using braces instead of the semicolon gets rid of the message:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\renewcommand\tikzmarkend[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[   
\begin{array}{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin{a}a&b&c\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


this should be the accepted answer, imho.

@cfr I should flag your comment for leading people astray

@DavidCarlisle I didn't know that was one of the options.

The fact that you get a message at all is a bug in the package adding an extra ; somewhere, but to address the general question of suppressing this warning....
By default it is a warning, you get on the terminal and in the log
Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!

This is because LaTeX sets
\tracinglostchars=2

Unless you have a very old system, you can make this an error by setting it to 3
If you add
\tracinglostchars=3

to your preamble TeX will stop with an error:
Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!
.
<argument> ...not:N \tex_shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...

l.10 \end{document}
                 
? 

If you set this to 1, it becomes a log message which is not shown on the terminal.
If you set it to 0 then missing characters are not logged so this has no message:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\tracinglostchars=0
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin{a}a&b&c\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}

although this will disable tracing of all missing characters not just the tikz nullfont feature.

Thank you for your help; until the bug is fixed, I will set \tracinglostchars=1.

I decided to mark @UlrikeFischer's solution as correct, per cfr's suggestion

@cfr just pinging you since I mentioned you in the previous comment.

@Jasper oh, so that's why I got the blame.

@cfr If you want, I could revert it back. Was I wrong in doing this, or are you guys just being light hearted?

@Jasper you didn't do anything wrong :-). ulrike's answer is safer. only david said it was my fault ulrike stole his tick. but if I tell you to revert it, ulrike will blame me instead ;).

@Jasper https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66715938#66715938

@Jasper sorry ignore us: we were just chatting.
