# Periods show up as hieroglyphs in TexMaker OS X

Tags: punctuation, texmaker, mac

I am getting the following strange and somewhat annoying behavior in TexMaker for OS X 10.9:

[image]

It happens any time a period immediately follows a curly brace.  Why?  Is there any way to fix this...?  Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Did you have a look at this in [issue tracker] (https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1186), may be changing the editor font would help.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution, but if you have some time on your hands, it would be nice if you could contribute to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134638/showcase-tex-typography-for-tugs-calendar).

Comment: @texenthusiast that does it! thanks!  You can post that link as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'm a grad student.  If I have time on my hands something is wrong ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate Q from unanswered Q's: Converting the Issue Tracker solution to community wiki.

Related Issue Tracker Link and Reply from Author:

https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1186

> You should try to use another font.
>   Nothing has changed in Texmaker about this : it's probably a trouble with Qt 5.2 on macosx mavericks

Comment: That link doesn't work any more. Changing the font to `Apple Braille` in texmaker seems to fix the issue.