# Invisible dots in texmaker editor

Tags: texmaker, mac

I recently downloaded Texmaker to my Mac running OS Lion. It works good apart from that i can't see my dots and commas in the tex editor. I've tried changing the font size but the problem persists. Has anyone had similar problems and are there any known solutions ?

Comment: They were lost in the dot-comma bust of 2000, no doubt `;^)`  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-com_bubble)

Comment: possibly Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154500/periods-show-up-as-hieroglyphs-in-texmaker-os-x

Comment: Yes thank you! I changed to font Apple Braille and now they are visible again.