# Strange symbol in place of full-stop in TexMaker

Tags: fonts, punctuation, texmaker, mac

Writing in texmaker these lines

```
(the mount heigh is $1200m$).
we saw it in \ref{chapter1}.
width=6.02099737532808in           (inside tikzpicture environment)
```

all the dots (fullstop) get replaced by this symbol

[image: strange symbol]

When I compile the document then it behaves like a dot, and get rendered as a dot/fullstop. Even if it's not a problem thou, I would like to understand what this symbol means and if it has some reason to exist...

Anyone has a clue?

EDIT:

Compilable version:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
(the mount heigh is $1200m$).
we saw it in \ref{chapter1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I said there is no error, nor wrong output during compilation. I add a compilable version, but this behaviour is only visible in the editor and not in the output. I guess this is only visible with TexMaker.

Comment: Go to Preferences >> Editor and check what the editor font encoding is. Is it UTF-8 or something else?

Comment: UTF-8. I'm running on a Mac

Comment: Found the solution here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154500/periods-show-up-as-hieroglyphs-in-texmaker-os-x?rq=1 I called it "strange symbol" and "fullstop" so didn't find that while looking through existing answers. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Use a monospaced font for the editor like `Lucida Sans Typewriter` or `DejaVu Sans Mono`

Comment: Monospaced ... thanks. Monotype is an old printing maschine

Comment: I encountered `teletype`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font to Apple Braille in texmaker editor fixes the problem.

Texmaker > Preferences > Editor > Editor font family > Apple Braille