# Sticky notes image

Tags: tikz-pgf, notes

I've tried looking in the site for this but I couldn't find anything (rather surprising).

I want a package (or even a TikZ drawing) to accomplish a note on a sticky note. I just need one note, so I don't mind a complex solution or a very specific solution to this problem.

Here are 2 possible examples of what I want:
[image]

Here is something better, but I don't own those images so I'll just put a link.

- [Sticky note](http://alaverdyan.com/readme/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/story.png)
- [Card](http://www.cuanmulligan.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/user-story-2.jpg)

I have no MWE since I want to know if there is a package. If there's not, I'll try with TikZ, though I'm not very good at it.

Comment: Where do you want to place these sticky notes? In the margin, or on the page? Does it need to overlap the text?  You should creae a MWE showing the usage. Just define `\newcommand{\StickyNote}[1]{}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill It will be on a beamer slide. I don't mind making a pdf with standalone and then insert the pdf as an image.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One basic possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (process using `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Humor Sans}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}

\NewDocumentCommand\StickyNote{O{6cm}mO{6cm}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
drop shadow={
  shadow xshift=2pt,
  shadow yshift=-4pt
},
inner xsep=7pt,
fill=myyellow,
xslant=-0.1,
yslant=0.1,
inner ysep=10pt
] {\parbox[t][#1][c]{#3}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\StickyNote{some text here\hfill\\\vfill And some more text \\\vfill And a third line}

\StickyNote[2.5cm]{\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\[4ex]\underline{what} so that \underline{why}}[6.5cm]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The basic command has the following syntax:

```
\MyStickyNote[<height>]{<text>}[<width>]
```

The font is Humor-Sans, which can be obtained in https://github.com/shreyankg/xkcd-desktop/blob/master/Humor-Sans.ttf.

Some other options using the [`fancypar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancypar) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Humor Sans}
\usepackage{fancypar}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}

\NewDocumentCommand\StickyNoteP{O{6cm}mO{6cm}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
drop shadow={
  shadow xshift=3pt,
},
inner xsep=0pt,
xslant=-0.1,
yslant=0.1,
inner ysep=0pt,
text depth=\the\dimexpr#1+2.5ex\relax
] {\parbox[t][#1][c]{#3}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\StickyNotePi{O{6cm}mO{6cm}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
draw,
fill=myyellow,
inner xsep=10pt,
xslant=-0.1,
yslant=0.1,
inner ysep=0pt,
text depth=\the\dimexpr#1+2.5ex\relax
] {\parbox[t][#1][c]{#3}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\StickyNoteP[2.5cm]{%
\NotebookPar[spiral=false]{
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]

\StickyNoteP[2.5cm]{%
\NotebookPar[spiral=false,intercolor=black,linecolor=white]{
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]

\StickyNotePi[2.5cm]{%
\UnderlinedPar[rulecolor=green]{%
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]

\StickyNotePi[2.5cm]{%
\MarkedPar{%
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]

\StickyNotePi[2.5cm]{%
\DashedPar{%
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with a bent corner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Humor Sans}
\usepackage{fancypar}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
% ... and possibly more
\backgroundpath{% this is new
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of ‘‘flipped page’’
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-10pt % this should be a parameter
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-10pt
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little corner
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
}
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand\StickyNote{O{6cm}mO{6cm}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
document,
draw,
drop shadow={
  shadow xshift=2pt,
  shadow yshift=-4pt
},
inner xsep=7pt,
fill=myyellow,
xslant=-0.1,
yslant=0.1,
inner ysep=10pt
] {\parbox[t][#1][c]{#3}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\StickyNotePi{O{6cm}mO{6cm}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
document,
draw,
fill=myyellow,
inner xsep=10pt,
xslant=-0.1,
yslant=0.1,
inner ysep=0pt,
text depth=\the\dimexpr#1+2.5ex\relax
] {\parbox[t][#1][c]{#3}{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\StickyNote{some text here\hfill\\\vfill And some more text \\\vfill And a third line}

\StickyNote[2.5cm]{\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\[4ex]\underline{what} so that \underline{why}}[6.5cm]

\StickyNotePi[2.5cm]{%
\UnderlinedPar[rulecolor=black]{%
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]

\StickyNotePi[2.5cm]{%
\DashedPar{%
\LARGE As \underline{who}, I want\\ \underline{what} so that \underline{why}}}[6.5cm]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I'll try adding some lines like the second link.

Comment: @Nico I added another option adding lines (you can customize the colors).

Comment: Just the little bent corners are left :-). Good answer by the way.

Comment: Nice! I'm having some errors with second code: "You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode."

Comment: @azetina the corners have been bent! :-)

Comment: @Nico I don't get any problems (but I use PGF version 3.0); try adding `\the` before `\dimexpr` in my code, as in `\the\dimexpr`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yep, that solved the problem. I'll leave the answer opened until tomorrow, just to see if there's another interesting answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You are really good at this. I always inspired by you and egreg just to mention a few.

Comment: +1 for not using the font which you surely know I'm referring to.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina now you are ready to make it a package. `\usepackage{StickyNotes}` =)

Comment: @Nico not a bad idea ;-) perhaps not a new package, but an extension to `fancypar`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/holtzermann17/34912a66cdfae3a28ca8 is a little letter-sized poster; I've had fun with this.  Thanks!!

Comment: I really enjoy using the first variant (starting with `\NewDocumentCommand\StickyNote{O{6cm}mO{6cm}}{%`). There's a side effect though: If you change the text color using `\color{green}`, the color is reset to black after using `\StickyNote`.