# How to get "and," "with," "for," etc. to print small and with diagonal banners behind

Tags: xetex, formatting, typography

There was a typography contest from which an answerer featured these diagonal instances of "and," "with," "for," etc. which were slightly tilted and had banner-like symbols behind them. How can I do this without purchasing a font?

---

[Showcase TeX Typography for TUG's Calendar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134638/showcase-tex-typography-for-tugs-calendar)

Comment: It's like the second answer. It has something like 66 votes.

Comment: It requires a font like the one used in the answer -- in that case, `Phaeton`, which has various 'catchwords' among its discretionary ligatures and 'banners' in its stylistic set ('stylistic set 2').  Finding a free font with all those, uhh, banners and ornaments might be hard.  The other way to do it for free is to design your own font (probably better to buy it unless you have lots of time and artistic ability, etc.).

Comment: Draw it. You don't have to use TeX for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the way how this is done is by getting a proper font capable of it. Font searching is not on-topic here in general.