# To get this WordCloud and R working in OSX's Texpad -1.6.0

Tags: bibtex, mac, r

I am trying to this [Hamilton's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146178/13173) about WordCloud, which uses R, working in OSX.
I have latest XCode and latest [R 3.1.1](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) (XCode5 support) installed.

### Texpad 1.4.7-1.6.0 problem

I open TexPad with your tikz file and the tex-file there. 
I edited only the path there to be exact.
Without compilation, I see

[image]

**Why there is the first page in the output?**

Then with compilation, I get errors

[image]

where log (my name replaced with masi here)

```
Auto-detecting the appropriate typesetting chain...

/usr/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp wordCloud.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./wordCloud.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9j> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx
.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty)
(/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
./wordCloud.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
l.16 ...newcommand{\\familydefault}{\\sfdefault}\n
                                                  ')
./wordCloud.tex:20: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal m
ode.
l.20                              col.outer  = "#
                                                 404040",
./wordCloud.tex:21: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal m
ode.
l.21                              col.inner  = "#
                                                 FFFFFF",

Overfull \hbox (49.61414pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--29
[]\OT1/phv/m/n/12 <<MakeCloud,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE>>= set.seed(1) sup-pressMes-
sages(library(bibcloud)) sup-pressMes-sages(library(tikzDevice)) op-tions(tikzD
ocumentDeclaration
(/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/WordCloud.tikz) [1] [5]
(/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.pdf (2 page
s).
SyncTeX written on /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.log.



/usr/texbin/xelatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp wordCloud.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./wordCloud.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9j> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx
.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty)
(/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
./wordCloud.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
l.16 ...newcommand{\\familydefault}{\\sfdefault}\n
                                                  ')
./wordCloud.tex:20: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal m
ode.
l.20                              col.outer  = "#
                                                 404040",
./wordCloud.tex:21: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal m
ode.
l.21                              col.inner  = "#
                                                 FFFFFF",

Overfull \hbox (49.61414pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--29
[]\OT1/phv/m/n/12 <<MakeCloud,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE>>= set.seed(1) sup-pressMes-
sages(library(bibcloud)) sup-pressMes-sages(library(tikzDevice)) op-tions(tikzD
ocumentDeclaration
(/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/WordCloud.tikz) [1] [6]
(/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.pdf (2 page
s).
SyncTeX written on /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/.texpadtmp/wordCloud.log.

~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
~
```

and particularly

[image]

There is a bug in TexPad 1.6.0 with R 3.1.1. 
Previous versions of TexPad also have the same bug. 
I am using 1.4.7.
Duncan's answer

> The simplest way to confirm this is if you could send us a file? There
>   were problems with Texpad's support of Knitr in 1.6.x, and for that
>   reason we have rewritten it from scratch in 1.7.0. If we have an
>   example of your code we can add it to the test suite and we will be
>   sure that it runs in 1.7.0

I reported this bug with the link to this post and necessary files to the developers. 
The test case will be included in 1.7.0 so no such a problem will be with Texpad 1.7.0 and R.

**How can you compile this thing in OSX?** Do not use TexPad 1.6.0. 
Just run pdflatex in terminal but not in OSX; use Linux.
This problem will be solved later after the beta period starts in 1.7.0.

> The problem is happening before the LaTeX stage,
>   whilst the R is processed and that is an issue with the installation of R - -.

### Everything alright with Pdflatex but want the R code for own WordCloud

The problem is I do not know what to expect as the output in the first place. 
**How should the R code work with LaTeX here? 
Which part is the R code? 
Can you comment and explain it?**

I run

```
pdflatex wordCloud.tex
```

and I get this [pdf-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qeovbu58b7a788g/wordCloud.pdf?dl=0) and this [log-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/og0fzi6zj0v2q6c/123.log?dl=0). 
It returns the same file as Hamilton has.

**How can you make an output that is specific to the files in my folder?** 
I think I need to run something that does *WordCloud.tikz* again.

I think this location is wrong in my attempts: **phd.bib**, since I do not have bibliography in my current document. 
**How can you go over this problem? 
Which else file can you use to pick up words?**

### Bibcloud with knitr 1.7 in OSX Yosemite (other versions too)

The problem is to install local package **bibcloud** and **tikzDevice**.

```
install.packages("tikzDevice", dependencies = TRUE)
```

and I run also in the R console

```
knit("/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/wordCloud/WordCloud.Rnw")
```

and everything ok still here

```
processing file: /Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/wordCloud/WordCloud.Rnw
  |......................                                           |  33%
  |...........................................                      |  67%
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code

output file: WordCloud.tex
```

but when I then compile the tex-file in Terminal

```
pdflatex WordCloud.tex
```

everything compiles with some warnings

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
...
Output written on WordCloud.pdf (2 pages, 30963 bytes).
Transcript written on WordCloud.log.
```

But when I now look in the file, I see there still the error with the package **tikzDevice**

```
## Error in library(bibcloud):  there is no package called ’bibcloud’
## Error in library(tikzDevice):  there is no package called ’tikzDevice’
## Error in withCallingHandlers(expr, message = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage")):  could not find function "cloud"
```

Hamilton's package **bibcloud** is not made for R 3.1.1. 
I got this error when tried to install it.

Comment: Please provide your LaTeX source file as shown in the screenshots in plain text in the question (formatted as code). One thing that differs from the TeXPad compilation and your compilation from the terminal is that TeXPad uses XeLaTeX, whereas you start pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Oh wait! It's in the answer you linked to. But I get the same error now when compiling with pdfLaTeX. I think you have to preprocess this file, as those `\\commands` suggest (and the illegal use of `#`s). My editor gives many warnings about the code in the middle of the file.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Mine too. I would appreciate if the author could document how to use the code.

Comment: as it says there the R is embedded inside the latex using "To integrate it with LaTeX, I used knitr" kintr is an R package you can find examples here or better at R doc I would guess (haven't used it myself) or you could remove the R portions and run R separately to generate the tikz then add it to a latex document by hand

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you point somewhere how to bind this R package with LaTeX by knitr?

Comment: @Masi sorry I don't have R (or therefore knitr) currently try http://yihui.name/knitr/ (why is this tagged bibtex by the way)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because the application uses Bibtex's data somehow.

Comment: Has someone has done the compilation of R and LaTeX with knitr here for OSX? I would expect so because a book written about it.

Comment: The .Rnw file as provided in my original competition submission depends on the custom R package. I have made the package available too : https://app.box.com/s/rqcxvpyghqb1yx3zg2ys

Comment: @NicholasHamilton Thank you for the addition of the package!