# How to work better with tables/columns in notes by LaTeX?

Tags: tables

There are many methods to work with tables but I would like to do it flexibly and generically for better collaboration and productivity. 
External mode in IDE would be nice. 
I can use any editors for this but find IDEs with many functionalities (etc TextMate in OSX) most suitable for the task, while TexPad is limited. 
I want to work with dynamic documents like with Knitr later but some bugs (one of mine discussion about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208970/13173)) has existed in OSX and/or editors which have slowed this approach.

Example of notes where a dummy table done by just writing it visually ok. 
I use underline for parts which have been verified by the teacher and are wanted to be there. 
Any external tool to inspect only this kinds of tables would be nice. 
My tables get often filled extensively because much comments and marks after many crafts:

```
 \section{Antiarrythmic drug classes}
 %% Sources
 % Merck ch. 213
 % Antiarrhytmics.pdf                               
 % anti-arrythmics-classification.jpg 
 %% Interactive tools
 % http://www.practicalclinicalskills.com/ekg-reference-guide.aspx                  
 \subsection{Rate control anti-arrhythmic}
 % Keywords: prevention, slow treatment 
                                                                       Arrythmia
1 a sodium channel blocker      \underline{procainamide}               V
  b sodium channel blocker      (Lidocaine),                           V
                                Phenytoin 
                                % no effect on QRS 
  c sodium channel blocker      propafeno                              SV
2 beta blockers                 propranolol, 
                                metoprolol, 
                                bisoprolol                                                                 
3 K ch. blocker                 \underline{amiodarone}, (sotalol)      V, TA 
4 Slow CCB non DHP              verapamil, diltiazem                   SV 
5 digoxin                       digoxin                                SV

%% Treatment of arrythmias
% Sometimes antiarrhythmic drugs, pacemakers, cardioversion-defibrillation, catheter ablation, or electrosurgery
```

where I would like to have some better mode for columns and/or tables - I heard that some column have/had existed in Emacs and old TextMate. 
Currently, I just add `verbatim` environment when the table is finished for notes, especially when I want to see the PDF fast.

**How to work better with tables for notes in TeX?**

Comment: Not knowing anything about who you're collaborating with, and how quickly you need to be able to take notes, I might suggest [Pandoc's table support](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables) in a Markdown document in TextMate using [this slightly unmaintained bundle](https://github.com/dsanson/Pandoc.tmbundle). You could even avoid the bundle if you run pandoc from a terminal as needed.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I write on average 95 words per minute, more than 100 words when I am not doing spell checking so the speed should not be the problem. Mostly, the presentation which I introduce to my classmates when I want to discuss my notes after the class again with them. Complicated Table format however is not possible because I have to rewrite things much. I like the format of Pandoc Table; mostly the multiline.

Comment: @MikeRenfro How can you use these Pandoc tables inside Tex environment? Is it advisable to just put them inside Verbatim environment? I notice that this table is compilable so some support for interaction should be included for them to print out dynamically. I do not know what the final output of the table provided as Community wiki should be below. One thing could be to make a script to my IDE editor (TextMate) which compiles selected table to PDF/image and provides after compilation a link in the filesystem to the file, below the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a pandoc document of:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                       Arrythmia
- ------------------------      ----------------------------------     ----------
1 a sodium channel blocker      \underline{procainamide}               V

  b sodium channel blocker      (Lidocaine),                           V
                                Phenytoin 
                                % no effect on QRS                              

  c sodium channel blocker      propafenon                             SV

2 beta blockers                 propranolol, 
                                metoprolol, 
                                bisoprolol                             

3 K ch. blocker                 \underline{amiodarone}, (sotalol)      V, TA        

4 Slow CCB non DHP              verapamil, diltiazem                   SV 

5 digoxin                       digoxin                                SV
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Rate Control anti-arrhythmics.
```

and a command line of `pandoc something.md -o something.tex` to make a LaTeX fragment, you get a longtable environment of:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
Arrythmia
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
1
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
a sodium channel blocker
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
\underline{procainamide}
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
V
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
b sodium channel blocker
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
(Lidocaine), Phenytoin \% no effect on QRS
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
V
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
c sodium channel blocker
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
propafenon
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
SV
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
2
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
beta blockers
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
propranolol, metoprolol, bisoprolol
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
3
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
K ch.~blocker
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
\underline{amiodarone}, (sotalol)
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
V, TA
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
4
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
Slow CCB non DHP
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
verapamil, diltiazem
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
SV
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.02\columnwidth}\raggedright
5
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\columnwidth}\raggedright
digoxin
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.43\columnwidth}\raggedright
digoxin
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
SV
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\caption{Rate Control anti-arrhythmics.}
\end{longtable}
```

which is obviously machine-generated code and not terribly readable as source. You can also use `pandoc -s something.md -o something.tex` to make a complete document. But the result ends up being:

[image]

I might also use `**word**` for bold emphasis instead of underlining with `\underline{word}`, but if you have an editor macro to type that for you, or if it's not a burden, don't worry about it.

See also [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245572/13173) about automating the extraction of markdown Pandoc tables in incomplete LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! I need to change my convention of using *underline* in items which have been verified by teacher or are wanted especially by the teacher. Brackets are used to mark things which can be left out. Bold, I often use in starting paragraphs and currently for questions, since I have not managed to make a flexible *exam* template like in Textmate with question -environment. - I get a similar output with your first command by including the packages `\usepackage{caption}; \usepackage{longtable}; \usepackage{booktabs}`. I think your output is sufficient for the task! Thank you!

Comment: I opened a new thread about the implementation of this script in some sufficient text editor here http://superuser.com/q/915932/2005 Actually, this is the capability what I really like http://stackoverflow.com/a/501698/54964 in those terminal editors.

Comment: You may find a more complete solution there, but for simple cases, you can use TextMate's `Text / Filter Through Command` menu. It will take the selected text (if any) or the entire document and pass it through a shell command. If the shell command is `pandoc -f markdown -t latex`, and you send the result to a new document, you'll get a LaTeX version of your table pretty quickly.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thank you for your comment! Something broken in my system, probably in $PATH or somewhere else, since I get `/bin/sh: pandoc: command not found`. I opened a new thread about it here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/187569/15504

Comment: Worst case, use the full path to pandoc (/usr/local/bin/pandoc by default).

Comment: @MikeRenfro I found a solution. Click the PATH box in settings.