# Referring to \chapter*

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters

In my document I used `\chapter*` to take out the number of the chapter in the title and in the table of content as below:

```
\chapter*{Chapter One\\ Introduction}\label{intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter One: Introduction}
```

However, I want to refer to the chapter in the document by the number, but when I used `\ref{intro}` I don't get the right number.

Is there is a way to refer to the chapter by number in the document while still keeping the title and table of content as is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why would you want to refer to something that has no number, hence isn't distinguishable in a unique way? (Yet there are a lot of other considerations too...)

Comment: Whay are you doing manual numbering and formatting? That is completely against LaTeX idea. Why `\chapter*{Chapter One\\ Introduction}\label{intro}\addcontentsline{...}{...}{...}` instead of `\chapter{Introduction}\label{intro}`?

Comment: \chapter* doesn't just not display the chapter number, it doesn't increment it either.  \chapter*{Introduction}\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{intro} will work.

Comment: Do you want to take out numbers of all chapters or this particular one. In case you want to take out chapters numbers of all chapters than this can be done.

Comment: Regarding @GonzaloMedina's comment you might find this useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248179/separate-content-from-formatting-i-e-just-type/254709#254709

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. `\chapter*{Introduction}\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{intro}` solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a solution for your problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % can be omitted
\usepackage{lmodern} % can be omitted in favor of another 

\usepackage{titlesec}   % Manipulates titles (this package is necessary)
\newcommand{\fancysecstyle}{ % This command will produce chapter without
% numbers
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{}
{}
{0pt}
{\Huge\bfseries}
}

\newcommand{\normalsecstyle}{% This command will produce normal chapters
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}
{\Huge\bfseries \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{20pt}
{\Huge\bfseries}
}

\begin{document}
\fancysecstyle % Switching off chapter numbers
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[1]

\normalsecstyle % Switching on chapter numbers if you want chapters from
% now on to have chapter number otherwise remove this command
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but my chapters are in two lines which I don't want to have in the table of content. I want to add this solution to the chapters title within the document but not the table of content. I want to have the table of content as  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter One: Introduction}`

Comment: Give the chapter command as following: `\chapter[Chapter One: Introduction]{Introduction}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}
    \lipsum[1-7]

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\let\thechapter\empty
\makeatother
\chapter{Chapter introduction}
\endgroup
\chaptermark{Chapter introduction}

\section{Section one}
    \lipsum[1-7]
\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{Section zzz}
    \lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```