# Amplifying fractions

Tags: math-mode, macros, formatting, fractions

I want to make myself a math portofolio (as a quick reference) and I have a part where I have to 'amplify' a fraction like here:

[image]

But I don't know how can I do this thing, can you help me? Thank you.

**Edit:** The "4)" in the upper left-hand corner means "amplify", the process of expanding both numerator and denominator by explicitly stating the value indicated as a multiplication factor.  Similarly, a "(4" in the upper right-hand corner means "simplify", or merge the separate values in the numerator and denominator to a single value.

Comment: And what exactly should `amplify` mean in this context?

Comment: @daleif The thing in the left corner, because eh, this is how we romanians and a part of the world do it.

Comment: @StefanAlecu -- please explain "amplify" in the text of the question.  i wasn't familiar with the term either until i read your response to daleif's question, although i was wondering what the "4)" meant.  (all the answers so far have neglected that component, and concentrated only on the coloring.)

Comment: @StefanAlecu -- i've edited in an explanation of "amplify" and "simplify", so that these terms can be found in a search.  (it's very hard to search on comments.)  if the explanation isn't correct, please fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define a set of custom markup commands (see [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/consistent-typography/29846#29846)], [[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248179/separate-content-from-formatting-i-e-just-type)]) for those fraction types, where you employ the `xcolor` package and the `\prescript` command from `mathtools` to do the needed formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

\newcommand{\coloredfrac}[3][red]{%
  \frac{\color{#1}#2}{\color{#1}#3}
}

\newcommand{\ampfrac}[3]{%
  \prescript{#1}{}{\frac{#2}{#3}}
}

\newcommand{\simpfrac}[3]{%
  \frac{#2}{#3}^{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\[ \ampfrac{4)}{1}{2}=\coloredfrac{1\cdot 4}{2\cdot 4}=\simpfrac{(4}{4}{8} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

Regarding your request for a more sophisticated coloring macro that is able to color the numerator and the denominator indipendantly you could define:

```
\newcommand\coloredfrac{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\coloredfrac@}{\coloredfrac@[red]}}
\def\coloredfrac@[#1]{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\coloredfrac@@[#1]}{\coloredfrac@@[#1][#1]}}
\def\coloredfrac@@[#1][#2]#3#4{%
  \frac{\color{#1}#3}{\color{#2}#4}
}
```

`\coloredfrac` can now be called

- without optional arguments to get a colored fraction in the default color, which is red in this example
- with one optional argument that sets the color for both, the numerator and the denominator
- with two optional arguments; the first one for the color of the numerator and the second one for the color of the denominator

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\coloredfrac{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\coloredfrac@}{\coloredfrac@[red]}}% default value: red
  \def\coloredfrac@[#1]{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\coloredfrac@@[#1]}{\coloredfrac@@[#1][#1]}}
  \def\coloredfrac@@[#1][#2]#3#4{%
    \frac{\color{#1}#3}{\color{#2}#4}
  }
  \makeatother

  %\newcommand{\ampfrac}[3]{%
  %  \prescript{#1}{}{\frac{#2}{#3}}
  %}

  %\newcommand{\simpfrac}[3]{%
  %  \frac{#2}{#3}^{#1}
  %}

  \begin{document}
  \[ \coloredfrac{1}{2}=\coloredfrac[green]{2}{4}=\coloredfrac[green][blue]{4}{8} \]
  \end{document}
  ```

[image: output_add]

Comment: Finally, one answer that answered my question. Thank you. Does it work the other way, to have (4 in the right corner? (that is what we call simplifying)

Comment: Sure, with something like: `\newcommand{\simpfrac}[3]{\frac{#2}{#3}^{#1}}`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[\raisebox{\baselineskip}{4)}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\textcolor{red}{1\cdot4}}{\textcolor{red}{2\cdot4}}=\frac{4}{8}\]
\[\raisebox{\baselineskip}{4)}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\textcolor{red}{1\cdot4}}{\textcolor{red}{2\cdot4}}=\frac{4}{8}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's good, but there is a problem. I want to display the thing in the left corner, the 4). That is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: while this takes care of the fractions, it doesn't cover the "4)" in the upper left corner.  (see comments on the question.  i didn't know what "amplify" meant either, until i read those.)

Comment: I guess it was also my fault that I didn't specify.

Comment: @StefanAlecu answer edited

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps mean something like "highlight" by "amplify"?

Anyway, I think

```
\newcommand{\colorfrac}[3][red]{\frac{{\color{#1} #2}}{{\color{#1} #3}}}
```

would suit your purpose.

```
\colorfrac{1}{2}
```

would give a red '1/2' and

```
\colorfrac[green]{1}{3}
```

a green one (needs the `color` package).

[image: colorfrac]

### Edit

As an answer to your comment: Of course you could, manually using `\frac{{\color{color1} 1}}{{\color{color2} 2}}` or by a command similar to the one defined above.

---

Okay, now I understood what you want. One solution (`\prescribe` in the other one is probably better, but still):

```
\newcommand{\amplfrac}[3]{\frac{\llap{$^{(#1)}$}#2}{#3}}
```

Comment: Nope, but at least now I know how to color fractions. Can you color individual parts of a fractions (the top only)?

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: I think for the individual coloring it is best to have a syntax with optional arguments, like `\colorfrac[<color-num>][<color-den>]{<num>}{<den>}` -- and `\colorfrac[<color-both>]{<num>}{<den>}` should be available too (see my answer).