# How to use italic bold with Zapf Chancery in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How to write a boldface italic in math mode when Zapf Chancery is used?

I used this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

    We define the following equation:
    \[\mathpzc{S} = \sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{1}{k^3}.\]


    Now let $\mathbf{x}$ be the following vector:
    \[\mathbf{x}=[x_1, \ldots, x_n]^\mathsf{T}\]

\end{document}
```

But, the vector 'x' is not italic. It looks more like if it was `\textbf{x}`.

Comment: Use the `bm` package and `\bm{x}`.

Comment: You should consider to mark your vector by `\vec{x}`, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258218/how-to-change-all-vec-to-bf/258286#258286 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248179/separate-content-from-formatting-i-e-just-type/254709#254709

Comment: There is no bold, is there? I don't have one. You can get faked bold e.g. with `bm` but that is always something of a compromise, of course.