# Replacing symbols

Tags: symbols

Shortly, I'd like to replace all the \vec{X} to \textbf{X} in my text. How could I do it automatically without having to rewrite all the thousands of vectors in my work?

Sorry if that's too simple, I'm just a noob.

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: use the search&replace functional provided by your editor

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258218/

Comment: Keep the semantics (...the usage of `\vec`) within your code, as it denotes something that represents a `\vec`tor. Instead add the following in your preamble: `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` such that `\vec` will be replaced by `\mathbf`.

Comment: Or, `\let\vec\mathbf`.

Comment: Mico, thank you so much! So easy to solve ;) . I'm using textstudio