# libertineGlyph and pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, characters, libertine

This is a follow-up question to [How to get Wikipedia W from Linux Libertine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47313/)

How can `\libertineGlyph{W.alt}` set with `pdflatex`? This MWE works fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\libertineGlyph{W.alt}ikipedia
\end{document}
```

with `XeTeX` and `LuaTeX` as well, but with `pdfLaTeX` the command is not available:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \libertineGlyph
                   {W.alt}ikipedia
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86319/21591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and use the [`libertine-legacy` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine-legacy) from CTAN.