# Writing Wikipedia logo in latex

Tags: beamer

How to write this logo in Latex? I am working on it, but could not get it.[image]

Comment: Please see if this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47339/3954 to [How to get Wikipedia W from Linux Libertine?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47313/3954) answers your question.

Comment: is there a reason to not simply include the image? If you look for example on http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Wikipedia-logo-de_riesig.png, you will find versions also in vector formate

Comment: @Ahmad For future reference, please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your effort so far. Your history reveals that you either pose one-line questions with no code or you ask people here to solve your homework assignments.

Comment: @Sverre Usually both :(.

Comment: Sir , this is not running in simple Latex and in beamer

Answer (score 3):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\char57391 ikipedia
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Same, run with xelatex. Includes small capitals "ikipedi" and capital "W" and "A".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\char57391\sc{ikipedi}A
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\sc` doesn't take an argument, so the shape would persist beyond the intended scope.  use either `\textsc{...}` or `{\scshape ...}`.

Comment: Sir , this is not running in simple Latex and in beamer

Comment: @Ahmad Correct, that's why you need to use xelatex or lualatex, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: But sir my whole document is in simple latex . How can I include this?

Comment: @Ahmad The special 'W' in the Wikipedia logo comes from the Linux Libertine font. The LaTeX fonts for Linux Libertine don't include this 'W', so you need to use the ``.otf`` fonts - and then you need to compile with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust this xelatex , because I cannot add any picture.

Comment: @Ahmad: Your document will probably work fine as is if you just use xelatex instead of pdflatex. Try it. If you have problems, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex